# Why does IE11 seem to be truncating my JS file?

Tags: javascript, angular, internet-explorer-11

Edit: I think I fixed this, and I think it had more to do with Angular than I thought. The script was actually breaking on a fat arrow but it was hard to see that because of the minification of the code. This script is a global script, and apparently is not compiled by babel when the project builds. I thought IE11 supported fat arrows, but apparently not? This is been fixed by converted any fat arrows in the file to traditional function declarations.

Full disclosure, I'm using Angular 7, but I don't have reason to believe at this point that it is relevant.

I am loading a third party JavaScript on my site, and the script has been obfuscated(?) and minified to some extent (by the third party, I do not have access to the original code). The code is smashed together into one very long, unintelligible line of code, and the function names have been converted to hex values? This aspect of the code puzzles me, as it does not appear to be an obfuscation where the code builds itself and/or provides something callable in english on the client. As far as I can tell, naming the functions hex values only provides a an obscurity to the code semantics. Again, I don't think this is necessarily relevant to my problem.

There is one function I am trying to call from this file, and this call works fine in non-IE browsers, but the function is undefined in IE11.

When I look at the request to load the file, comparing Firefox and IE11, I'm noticing some weirdness. For brevity, I'm posting screenshots of the *END* of the file contents, as the code is long, and I don't believe it is necessary to show the entirety of the file to pose my question.

In the FF response preview, as well as when I open the response in a new tab, I'm seeing the full file contents, including the function declaration I'm attempting to call:

[image: FF response]

In the IE response preview and when copying the actual response payload, I'm seeing what appears to be a truncated version of the file, and the file is ending before the declaration of the function I'm attempting to call:

[image: IE response]

Can anyone explain this difference in the payload on IE11? I recall older versions of IE truncating large bundles of code, but I believe the file size limit on IE is greatly increased in IE11 and my file is only 25kb.

Lastly, another oddity I noticed was that when I copy and paste the response payload directly from the FF preview, the pasted code is truncated just like the IE payload seems to be, at the exact same spot.

Comment: Try loading the script into a tab in each browser, and use the Save As... device to compare them using Diff or your IDE. I wonder if it is just an oddity in one of the Developer Toolbar preview windows.

Comment: @halfer it's not just the preview that is different. When you open the actual payload there is a clear truncation of the file on the IE version

Comment: Maybe you have a 'null' character in the place it is truncated, might explain it.

Comment: Alright, can you grab the file via Curl or Postman to see a canonical version of the file?

Comment: My best guess would be to check whether the Content-Length header matches the actual file size while taking into consideration that this may differ due to the transfer encoding... try running your web app on a different webserver, try different settings for gzip and deflate as possible transfer encodings on your webserver... searching the web for that, I found many complaints about IE6 up to Edge truncating downloaded files. No solution found, but it's often being correlated to content-length, gzip and/or deflate.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or copied and edited to create a solution.**

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed this, and I think it had more to do with Angular than I thought. The script was actually breaking on a fat arrow but it was hard to see that because of the minification of the code. This script is a global script, and apparently is not compiled by babel when the project builds. I thought IE11 supported fat arrows, but apparently not? This is been fixed by converted any fat arrows in the file to traditional function declarations.